# Erroring out creating an ECDSA Key pair with pkcs11interop

Tags: pkcs#11, ecdsa, hsm, gemalto, pkcs11interop

I am connecting to Gemalto HSM which supports secp256r1. I have the following code to create an ECDSA key pair using Pkcs11interop. I am getting the paramsBytes using BouncyCastle NistNamedCurves and X962Parameters.

The HSM keeps comming back with CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID. I am new to ECDSA so I may have missed something. Any ideas?

```
                X9ECParameters x9Ec = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
                X962Parameters x962 = new X962Parameters(x9Ec);
                byte[] paramsBytes =  x962.GetDerEncoded();

                // The CKA_ID attribute is intended as a means of distinguishing multiple key pairs held by the same subject
                byte[] ckaId = session.GenerateRandom(20);

                // Prepare attribute template of new public key
                List<ObjectAttribute> publicKeyAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
                publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, false));
                publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, keyName));
                publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ID, ckaId));
                publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_VERIFY, true));
                publicKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ECDSA_PARAMS, paramsBytes));

                // Prepare attribute template of new private key
                List<ObjectAttribute> privateKeyAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
                privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, true));
                privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, keyName));
                privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ID, ckaId));
                privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SENSITIVE, true));
                privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SIGN, true));
                privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ECDSA_PARAMS, paramsBytes));

                // Generate key pair
                Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_ECDSA_KEY_PAIR_GEN);
                ObjectHandle publicKeyHandle = null;
                ObjectHandle privateKeyHandle = null;
                session.GenerateKeyPair(mechanism, publicKeyAttributes, privateKeyAttributes, out publicKeyHandle,
                    out privateKeyHandle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out what was going on. The HSM did not like the

```
privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ECDSA_PARAMS, paramsBytes));
```

on the private key. PKCS states that the ECDSA params need to be on the public key and can't be on the private key and this implementation enforced that.

Answer (score 0):

In CKA_ECDSA_PARAMS  you can insert a byte[] which is specific for any curve name. a list of available names and related byte[] are presented [here](https://github.com/trivialmips/openssl/blob/10a781b4ee80c990914da03f7538aa08e865a81e/crypto/objects/obj_dat.h) at SSL GitHub project.

Another thing, add `(CKA.TOKEN, true)` as other attributes for private key.